# NamedQuery with Child Class

Tags: jpa

I have a persistence model like this one :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CMM_DT_EMPLOYEE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "EMP_TYPE")        
public abstract class Employee {
    @Id
    protected Integer employeeId;
    ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "FULL")
public class FullTimeEmployee extends Employee {
    protected Integer salary;
    // ...`enter code here`
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "PART")
public class PartTimeEmployee extends Employee {
    protected Float hourlyWage;
}
```

Named query (`select c from FullTimeEmployee c`) not working. Its returning only one row although there are many rows for this discriminator type in the Employee Table. Please help.

Comment: add full config with discriminators and other annotations like Table

Comment: added the discriminator

Comment: add also the config of EMP_TYPE column

Comment: What sql is invoked? Aka debugging

Comment: in the EMP_TYPE COLUMN  we are are storing just the varchar2  string ie FULL or PART.